# How to Use 2nd Monitor with Excel 2002

Tags: microsoft-excel-2002

How do I go about moving an Excel spreadsheet from my main monitor to my 2nd one while still being able to process other spreadsheets in monitor #1?

Answer (score 5):

You may have to open two instances of Excel. The best way I know how to do this is to *not* double-click your .xls files in Explorer, but to open two Excels from the Start menu, put one on the other monitor, then use the Open dialog.